# tum simulator takeoff not working

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ardrone-autonomy, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I installed tum simulator and ardrone_autonomy and I have gazebo launching with a scene and I can see the drone but when I do `rostopic pub -1 ardrone/takeoff std_msgs/Empty` nothing happens.
when I do `rostopic list` I get:

```
/ardrone/bottom/camera_info
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/compressed
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/compressedDepth
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/theora
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/bottom/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/ardrone/bottom/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/bottom/parameter_updates
/ardrone/front/camera_info
/ardrone/front/image_raw
/ardrone/front/image_raw/compressed
/ardrone/front/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/front/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/ardrone/front/image_raw/compressedDepth
/ardrone/front/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/front/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/ardrone/front/image_raw/theora
/ardrone/front/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/front/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/ardrone/front/parameter_descriptions
/ardrone/front/parameter_updates
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/ground_truth/state
/ground_truth_to_tf/euler
/ground_truth_to_tf/pose
/joint_states
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

When I publish to takeoff and do `rostopic list` I can see that `/ardrone/takeoff` gets added
`rosnode list` gives me:

```
/gazebo
/ground_truth_to_tf
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
```

I am using ROS kinetic, but couldn't find good installations for it so I ended up installing indigo things.
I didn't manage to install the ardrone_helpers but I understand that it isn't compulsory. Otherwise I did the installation from the ros website. The way I figure it I a publishing but the node for the drone is not subscribed to that topic for some reasen

I have spent more than 10 hourse trying to figure out what I did wrong and I got nothing, any help would be greatly appriciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269716/tum-simulator-takeoff-not-working/) by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Where did you install `tum_simulator` from? The one listed in the wiki is for Hydro. Many packages for Indigo *may* work on Kinetic but there's no guarantees. You're best bet is to use the correct version of the package for your version of ROS (although I don't know of `tum_simulator` for Kinetic).

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Check this answer https://answers.ros.org/question/251601/is-there-a-simulator-for-ardrone-in-ros-kinetic/

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-03-13**:
I went back through my posts and saw that I forgot to update, so for anyone looking in the future I did end up using: https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator which is what was mentioned in jayess's link, Thanks!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-13**:
@oha if my answer solved your problem then please click the check mark to mark it as correct.

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-03-13**:
I cant find a check mark next to a comment.. I only found an up arrow, is that what you meant? I am very sorry about this, I am trying to get better at using forums and contributing but am still struggling a bit..

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-13**:
No worries. The check mark is next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer in this link may help you: https://answers.ros.org/question/251601/is-there-a-simulator-for-ardrone-in-ros-kinetic/

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1